# What are the different ways to implement a button in Android java?

Tags: java, android

I know these two:

1. `Button b = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.Button2));`
2. `android:onClick=""`

Are there any different ways?

I just tried `Button b = new Button();`

But it did not work in android!

Thank you!

Comment: There is two way to show button in android one is define button in xml and another one is try to add button at run time.

Comment: Why button b = new button(); don't work while it works in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Button b = (Button) (findViewById(R.id.Button2));

This gives you object of the button defined in XML.

2.android:onClick=""

This method is for handling button click event, and not for creating button.

3.Default constructor is not available - `new Button()`

You need to pass context in the constructor.

```
Button delete = new Button(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button programmatically, try this:

```
ViewGroup linearLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutID);
```

Then you can create a new Button for example and just add it:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("MyButton");
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linerLayout.addView(btn);
```

Comment: Welcome, glad to help ^^

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFromXml"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button From Xml"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrActivityButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private  Button btnFromXml;
    private LinearLayout lnrActivityButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnFromXml = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFromXml);
        lnrActivityButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrActivityButton);

        btnFromXml.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"XML Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Button btnFromActivty = new Button(this);
        btnFromActivty.setText("Button From Activity");
        btnFromActivty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Activity Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        lnrActivityButton.addView(btnFromActivty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

**Programaticaly:**

```
Button b=new Button(this);
yourView.addView(b);
```

**By Xml(Using Layouts)**

```
          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
           />
```